# Question about functions on the fibers of a finite unramified map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $ X $ and $ Y $ be algebraic varieties over a field $ k $ with $ Y $ nonsingular. Suppose $ f : X \rightarrow Y $ is a finite unramified map.

In Shafarevich's "Basic Algebraic Geometry I", the author states:

> Consider a function $ a \in A = k[X] $ that takes distinct values at all the points of the inverse image $ f^{-1}(y) $ of some point $ y \in Y. $ Then $ k(X) = k(Y)(a). $

Why is $ k(X) = k(Y)(a)? $

Since $ f $ is finite, $ k[X] $ in integral over $ k[Y], $ so $ a $ is integral over $ k[Y]. $ But I am not sure how this implies the statement above.